# Ошибка 401 при простом запросе к сайту

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, httpwebrequest

Через браузер все работает. Здесь же простой гет запрос выдает ошибку 401. Что не так в этом запросе?

```
using(WebClinet webClient = new WebClient())
{
  var data = webClient.DownloadString("https://login.mts.ru/amserver/UI/Login");
}
```

Comment: Какой тип аутентификации на сайте включен? Виндовый?

Comment: ну так я даже не авторизуюсь)) хочу просто страничку загрузить

Comment: Так указанная страница и возвращает код 401 при открытии в браузере. Это ее нормальное состояние. Контент при этом она тоже возвращает.